# React and firebase setState 'you must specify the "to" property'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I tried many hours but can't seem to find what I am doing wrong, I am new to react so I really appreciate your help. I first had an array state of accommodations, then I looped through them with a map function and everything was ok. But after I connected firebase with the project the map function didn't work because firebase was an object so I had to change the map function and assign Object.keys first. Then there is an error that says 'you must specify the "to" property' highlighting me the setState method. I have an image attached to the error. I am so sorry for my poor English, thank you so much for your help

[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4uQZ.png)

[image]

Comment: Could you please include the relevant code and the error in text format in the question, instead of linking to external images?

Comment: Thank you very much and I'm sorry for not specifying more details, I fixed the problem. It was because I didn't use the map function correct and it returns nothing which made Link component of ReactRouter to throw an error. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I used incorrect structure for `<Link>` component in an other file related to this file.

Wrong structure :

```
<Link href="...">
```

Correct structure :

```
<Link to="...">
```

after this change, it's ok.